# Security prompt about Microsoft Silverlight in IE11

Tags: silverlight, internet-explorer-11

I am working on a Sharepoint 2010 site. I am testing my site behaviour on IE 11.

When I log on to my site I am getting a security prompt about allowing 'npctrl.dll' which is 'Microsoft Silverlight' add-on file. This message appears on every page. This is causing bad user experience.

When I allowed npctrl.dll on one of the pages, It showed me next security prompt with following message: **This webpage Wants to run 'Microsoft Silverlight' which isn't compatible with Internet Explorer's enhanced security features.**

I read somewhere that this prompt is coming due to enabled enhanced protected mode in IE11 browser.

Please let me know if it can be solved by any work-arounds.

Thanks in advance. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is this when running on the server?  I have seen Enhanced Security on servers but not on desktop OS.  Can you turn off the Enhanced Security? I know you can on the server OS.

Comment: This is unrelated to ESC, this is EPM.

Comment: I got here by searching for 'npctrl.dll' permission warning from outlook.com in IE11.  Is npctrl.dll related to this Silverlight EPM discussion?

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight is a legacy plugin which is no longer actively developed. As a consequence, it does not support running inside [Enhanced Protected Mode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2012/03/23/understanding-ie10-enhanced-protected-mode-network-security-addons-cookies-metro-desktop.aspx)'s AppContainers. EPM is a security feature first introduced in IE10 and enabled by default in the desktop for IE11.

Microsoft has indicated that they're "looking at" possibly updating Silverlight to work in EPM but given that the team was effectively dissolved years ago, I wouldn't hold my breath.

The simplest workaround for this issue is to place the sites in question in Internet Explorer's Trusted Zone, which runs outside of EPM.

The long-term workaround for this issue is to migrate away from Silverlight in the browser; either replace the site with an app that runs outside the browser, or move to HTML5.

Comment: *gasp* eric i don't think you are supposed to publicly acknowledge that silverlight is dead :)

Comment: The sad bit is that Microsoft assumes that everyone can easily see that Silverlight is dead and thus refuses to confirm that. In contrast, some Silverlight developers with less perspective can't see that it has no future and refuse to believe it without an official statement.